# Construction of $(p)$-local spectrum.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectra

I have a question regarding the construction of the $p$-local spectrum of a given spectrum $X$. I have seen in many papers people defining the dual notion of it, namely the $p$-completion of $X$, $X_p^{\wedge}:= L_{M(\mathbf{Z}/p)}X$, but never actually someone giving the precise definition/construction of the $p$-local spectrum. So I was wondering if anyone is able to give this definition/construction of the $p$-local spectrum associated to a spectrum $X$, or to provide a reference of it.

P.S.
Regarding the reference; as it has been mentioned in the comments section, I am aware of the standard reference (Bousfield's paper) but I cannot understand where he defines the $p$-local spectrum construction of a spectrum $X$. Thus for a reference am looking for something more handy.

Comment: A. Bousfield, The localization of spectra with respect to homology, Topology vol. 18, 1979

Comment: I have checked that paper (which is the starting point of this idea); so is $X_{(p)}$  just defined the Bousfield localization with respect a prime number $p$?

Comment: If you want some explicit construction, then you can take your favourite spectrum $M$ and take homotopy colimit of diagram looking like $M \to M \to M \dots$, where arrows are multiplication by all $p$-free natural numbers in some order. Informally, localization with respect to some good class of morphisms (e. g. giving isomorphism on some homology theory) is obtained by taking homotopy colimit by all endomorphisms in that class. (It's not true as stated, but IMO gives good sense of how it looks).